# Docker ADD doesn't extract file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to download a specific Node version and copy the binary from the extracted tar.xz, but it doesn't look like `ADD` actually extracts the file.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/debian:stretch-slim

ENV nodever="v6.10.0"
ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/${nodever}/node-${nodever}-linux-armv7l.tar.xz /
COPY /node-${nodever}-linux-armv7l/bin/node /

RUN cat /etc/issue && \
\
apk update &&  \
apk add \
    dnsmasq \
    hostapd \
    iptables

RUN mkdir app
ADD start.sh /app/start.sh
ADD server /app/server

ADD configs/hostapd.conf /etc/hostapd.conf
ADD configs/dnsmasq.conf /etc/dnsmasq.conf

WORKDIR /app
CMD ["/app/start.sh"]
```

but running `docker -v build` yields this error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.728kB
Step 1/12 : FROM arm32v7/debian:stretch-slim

---> 1510cdc40eca
Step 2/12 : ENV nodever "v6.10.0"

---> Using cache
---> 1ca3d2f72a3c
Step 3/12 : ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/${nodever}/node-${nodever}-linux-armv7l.tar.xz /
Downloading   8.34MB/8.34MB

---> a1fefb9bda66
Step 4/12 : COPY /node-${nodever}-linux-armv7l/bin/node /
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder233292954/node-v6.10.0-linux-armv7l/bin/node: no such file or directory
```

I've tried running `RUN ls /` which shows that it has downloaded the archive but it isn't extracted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [documented](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add):

> If  is a *local* tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory.

Notice the emphasis on "local".

This was actually changed and [reverted](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33849) at some point, so it's unlikely this will ever change again.

Comment: Oh my bad, thank you! I took a bit of the Dockerfile from an example so I thought it was correct, but it was probably made before the change was reverted.

Comment: I just added a second `ADD` afterwards to extract the downloaded archive but now that `ADD` doesn't find the archive..? I'm honestly lost, it's difficult to debug Dockerfiles

Comment: `ADD` and `COPY` are used to transfer files from the build context (what's sent to the Docker daemon by the Docker builder, referenced by the PATH/URL argument to docker-build(1)) and an intermediary container to be committed at the relevant step. So, either you download the archive outside the build procedure (Dockerfile) and into the context, then `ADD` it to the image, or you download *and* extract the archive with a `RUN` step (e.g. curl | xz | tar) within the build procedure. You would never have two `ADD` steps for the scenario you outline.